# Update object into array MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

Suppose you have the following documents in my collection:

```
{foo:[{
    bar1:{_id:1, active: true},
    bar2:{_id:2, active: true}
  },{}]
}
```

Do query:

```
db.test.update({$or: [
    {'foo.bar1._id': 1)},
    {'foo.bar2._id': 1}
  ]
},
{$set: {'foo.?????.active': false}})
```

Result:

```
{foo:[{
    bar1:{_id:1, active: false},
    bar2:{_id:2, active: true}
  },{}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
db.test.update({"foo.0.bar1._id" : 1}, {$set : {"foo.0.bar1.active" : "false"}})
```

Or

```
db.test.update({"foo.0.bar1.active" : "true"}, {$set : {"foo.0.bar1.active" : "false"}})
```

here foo.0 is index.

Thanks.